# How to copy a user's message in a bot embed

Tags: discord.js, embed, emoji

I want to make a command using 2 files to do a fully customizable embed.
*In the first file :* When the user do the command 2 embeds appears, the first is empty and the second has options with emojis we can react [See the base I already did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rldIg.jpg)

*In the second file :* I made that when the user react with the first emoji, the bot sends a message saying "*please specifiate an embed title*"

But now I don't now what to do to make the bot copy the user's message and paste it in the first embed as a title.

I tried things like

```
    switch (emoji) {
      case "️":
        message.channel.send('Spécifie un titre d\'embed !')
        const filter = m => (message.author.id === m.author.id)
        const userEntry = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
          max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ['time']
        });

        if(!member.user.bot) {
          if(userEntry) {
            const newEmbedModifTitle = userEntry.content;
            modifembed.setTitle(`${newEmbedModifTitle}`)
            message.edit(modifembed);
          }
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

But or the bot copies the message "*please specifiate an embed title*" and paste it in the second embed, or it don't do anything.

I hope someone can help me !

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to just do `!send [Title] [Color] [Footer] [Show author] [Content]` then split it in a args[] let.